# Bayesian update in pymc3: adding more data doesn't work

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am new to pymc3, but I've heard it can be used to build a Bayesian update model.  So I tried, without success.  My goal was to predict which day of the week a person buys a certain product, based on prior information from a number of customers, as well as that person's shopping history.

So let's suppose I know that customers in general buy this product only on Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, and Thursdays only; and that the number of customers who bought the product in the past on those days is 3,2, 1, and 1, respectively.  I thought I would set up my model like this:

```
import pymc3 as pm

dow = ['m', 'tu', 'w','th']
c = np.array([3, 2, 1, 1])

# hyperparameters (initially all equal)
alphas = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
with pm.Model() as model:
    # Parameters of the Multinomial are from a Dirichlet
    parameters = pm.Dirichlet('parameters', a=alphas, shape=4)
    # Observed data is from a Multinomial distribution
    observed_data = pm.Multinomial(
        'observed_data', n=7, p=parameters, shape=4, observed=c)
```

So this set up my model without any issues.  Then I have an individual customer's data from 4 weeks: 1 means they bought the product, 0 means they didn't, for a given day of the week.  I thought updating the model would be as simple as:

```
c = np.array([[1, 0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1])

with pm.Model() as model:
    # Parameters are a dirichlet distribution 
    parameters = pm.Dirichlet('parameters', a=alphas, shape=4)
    # Observed data is a multinomial distribution
    observed_data = pm.Multinomial(
        'observed_data',n=1,p=parameters,  shape=4, observed=c)    

    trace = pm.sample(draws=100, chains=2, tune=50, discard_tuned_samples=True)
```

This didn't work.

My questions are:

- Does this still take into account the priors I set up before, or does it create a brand-new model?
- As written above, the code didn't work as it gave me a "bad initial energy" error.   Through trial and error I found that parameter "n" has to be the sum of the elements in observations (so I can't have observations adding up to different n's).  Why is that?  Surely the situation I described above (where some weeks they shop only on Mondays, and others on Mondays and Thursday) is not impossible?

Is there a better way of using pymc3 or a different package for this type of problem?    Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific questions first:

- The second model is a *new* model. You can reuse context managers by changing the line to just `with model:`, but looking at the code, that is probably not what you intended to do.
- A multinomial distribution takes `n` draws, using the provided probabilities, and returns one list. `pymc3` will broadcast for you if you provide an array for `n`. Here's a tidied version of your model:

```py
with pm.Model() as model:
    parameters = pm.Dirichlet('parameters', a=alphas)
    observed_data = pm.Multinomial(
        'observed_data', n=c.sum(axis=-1), p=parameters, observed=c)    

    trace = pm.sample()
```

You also ask about whether `pymc3` is the right library for this question, which is great! The two models you wrote down are well known, and you can solve the posterior by hand, which is *much* faster: in the first model, it is a `Dirichlet([4, 3, 2, 2])`, and in the second `Dirichlet([5, 2, 1, 2])`. You can confirm this with PyMC3, or [read up here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution).

If you wanted to expand your model, or chose distributions that were not conjugate, then PyMC3 might be a better choice.